# linux command to replace specified content at the end of line

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a file(sample1.txt) of the following form:

```
1    a
2    b\
3    d
4    e\
5    k
6    hello\hi
7    stackoverflow\site\
```

Now if the last character of a line is a  '\' then I want to replace it with '', such that I convert sample1.txt to the following file:

```
1    a
2    b
3    d
4    e
5    k
6    hello\hi
7    stackoverflow\site
```

I know it is possible to do the same using a programming language, but is it possible to do the same using a linux command (like grep, sed, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
cat sample1.txt | sed 's/\\$//'
```

Comment: Can you please explain what sed is doing in the command a bit..i mean i am unable to understand as to what do 's/\\$//' stand for

Comment: Sorry - it can be a bit cryptic.  The "\\" matches the single backslash in your input text (it has to be doubled up since backslash by itself has special meaning = eg "\t" is tab).  The "$" is the pattern to recognise end-of-line - so "\\$" matches "Backslash at end of line". So, the whole thing "s/\\$//" means "substitute the backslash at the end of the line with nothing"

Answer (score 1):

With Sed you can do the following:

```
sed -i 's/\\$//' samples.txt
```

s will start the substitution. // is what is match against. In this case the first \ is so the second \ which is what you are looking to replace is used literally and not as a part of the sed command \ = match a \ while \ alone means something completely different. $ means to look for the first instance from the end of the line so you do not match any of the other "\"s within the line.

// is the end of the first pattern match and the start of the replacement text so if you where to do /test/ the / at the end of the file would be replaced with the test and the output will look something like

```
sed -e 's/\\$/test/' sample.txt 
1    a
2    btest
3    d
4    etest
5    k
6    hello\hi
7    stackoverflow\sitetest
```

The -i in the sed command will do an inline replace so it modifies the file and does not print to STDOUT

```
  -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

Additional reading on [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check with,

```
 # cat checkin.sh
 root/
 postfix/
 root/
 postfix/

 # sed -i 's/\/$//g' checkin.sh  ----> to remove last / in file.

 # cat checkin.sh
 root
 postfix
 root
 postfix

 # sed -i 's/$/\//g' checkin.sh  -----> to add / in every line's end.

 # cat checkin.sh
 root/
 postfix/
 root/
 postfix/
```

Thanks.